# nrow() return null when I am referring to the data frame using index

Tags: r

I am trying to create a for loop which will create a new column in each of the data frame that I have, and the value of each cells in the column equals to the name of the dataframe. Anyways, I am encountering this issue when I trying to employ the for loop.

```
dflist <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4) 
dflist_name <- c('df1', 'df2', 'df3', 'df4')
```

when I use this:

```
nrow(df1)
>1000
nrow(dflist[1])
>NULL
```

eventually I want to do this:

```
for (i in 1:length(dflist)) {
  cbind(dflist[i], rep(dflist_name[i], nrow(dflist[i])))
```

Can someone help explain this issue?

Comment: you need to use `[[`. `nrow(dflist[[1]])`

Comment: If your list is a train with many cars then `dflist[1]` is a train consisting of just the first car. `dflist[[1]]` is the contents of the first car. Call `typeof(dflist[1])` and `typeof(dflist[[1]])`

Comment: @svenhalvorson Your comment is helpful! Thank you.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Make sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you create a nested df with your dataframes in a column and their names in another column, you can use the `unnest` function in `tidyr`. Here's an example:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(
  a = rbinom(10, 1, .5),
  b = rbinom(10, 1, .5)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  c = rbinom(10, 1, .5),
  d = rbinom(10, 1, .5)
)

df3 <- data.frame(
  e = rbinom(10, 1, .5),
  f = rbinom(10, 1, .5)
)

file_names = c('df1', 'df2', 'df3')

dflist <- list(df1, df2, df3) 

df_nest <- data_frame(
  file_contents = dflist,
  file_name = file_names) 

df_all <- unnest(df_nest)
```

This will give you a single dataframe with a column describing the name of the dataframe where each obs comes from.

edit: You can then split the dataframe by column values if you want separate dfs.